# cabal install an executable from Hackage via a sandbox?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I run `cabal install [pkg]` and pkg is a command line executable program instead of a library, it often warns me with this message: "Warning: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls"

I always use the `--force-reinstalls` option to proceed.

But since I'm installing an executable and NOT a library, is there a way to run `cabal install` to isolate the build process in a cabal sandbox, and then install the executable in `~/.cabal/bin`? Or is this something I need to write a custom bash script for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always create a sandbox for my tools, such as `hoogle`, `pointfree`, `haddock`, `ghc-mod`, `hlint`, `shake`, and `stylish-haskell` among others.  Simply follow these steps:

- Create a cabal sandbox with `cabal sandbox init` in the location of your choice
- Run `cabal install [pkg1 [pkg2 ...]]`
- Once completed, copy the desired executables from the `.cabal-sandbox/bin` folder to your `~/.cabal/bin/` folder.
- Run `cabal sandbox delete` to remove the likely very large sandbox that you no longer need.

These executables are usually completely standalone, so you can build them against the dependencies they request in a sandbox and then move them to where ever you want.  This definitely helps keep your system-wide installation clean and free from conflicts.

Comment: Does that mean there is no automatic way to copy the executables?

Comment: @Sam `cp .cabal-sandbox/bin/* ~/.cabal/bin/` isn't very hard. This isn't a feature of cabal, they don't assume that you're using a sandbox for building these tools.  They don't assume anything really, your sandboxes are your own and considering this is a step I usually perform once after installing Haskell I don't see the use case for adding this to cabal.

Comment: If you use a cabal sandbox, and you install something like hpack, how do you actually execute it? When I run `hpack`, it says it cannot find the command (because it's no on PATH most likely). Is there a `cabal run` sort of command that runs within the context of the sandbox?

Comment: Oh I found it as `cabal exec hpack`.